# Login Authentication Mechanism - Proper way for client to send username/password

Tags: security

I am curious how to properly send username and password from a website login form to a server.

If I just send the username and password without hashing them to an https server how exposed is the password I send in a **POST** request to somebody sniffing the package and finding out the password? The server is https enabled.

What would be the proper methodology to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is HTTPS enabled then any data going over the wire will be encrypted. It would be extraordinarily difficult for a network-only attacker to sniff even a plaintext password over HTTPS without one of the parties noticing.

HTTPS uses SSL/TLS on the transport layer, which is designed to provide both encryption and authentication. The SSL/TLS protocol, as part of its handshake, negotiates a symmetric encryption key that is different for each session and is used with a strong algorithm to protect data on the wire.

To mitigate 'man-in-the-middle' attacks, the asymmetric keys used by the client and server to establish a shared encryption key are also cryptographically signed by a certificate authority, both to provide assurance of trust and to prevent modification of the certificate. As long as the certificate authority can be trusted, it is easy to check the signature and and server name on the certificate itself. All modern browsers do this automatically and throw a warning to the user if there is any problem with the certificate.

As long as you and your users are aware of the issues surrounding the proper use of SSL (e.g. keep your private key safe, and make sure your users pay attention to browser warning), it's fine to send plaintext passwords over an SSL connection.

If the demands of your application are such that you cannot do even that, you might consider X.509 authentication (which uses certificates on the client side as well as the server side) or Kerberos authentication (which sends no passwords over the wire). For a basic web application, though, both of these solutions are overkill.